# Printing the id of the function from within the function in python

Tags: python

How can i find the id of the function from within the function in python

```
def countmem(a):
    if a==0:
        return
    print("count is ",id(countmem))
    countmem(a-1)


countmem(4)
```

As every function is called in its own namespace in recursion how can we obtain different id for each function call. This is giving same id for all calls

Comment: what makes you think you should get a different id each time?

Comment: The local variables are held on a stack. The function itself is ‘static’ (or a singleton) and always has the same id. In the case of your function, why not use ‘a’ as the id?

Comment: Means only a namespace is created not a copy of the function object. if a create a local variable in this function will it have a different id for each call.kindly update

Comment: Your code is already finding the `id` of the function.  You're under the misconception that the `id` of a function depends on the context.  It doesn't.  It will only change if you redefine the function.

Comment: if the value is the same, the id probably won't change

Comment: @diggusbickus An `id` is constant for a given object over its entire lifetime.  If the function is changed, the old `id` becomes available and may be reused, but it has nothing to do with the function definition itself.

Comment: sorry i wasn't clear, i was answering to "if a create a local variable in this function will it have a different id for each call"

Comment: @TomKarzes what this means is when we call a function python creates an object for that and repeated calls to it is calling the same object with different local variable stack.is it so

Comment: @diggusbickus For certain immutable types, it may reuse the same object.  This can happen with small integers, bool values. `None`, and sometimes certain strings.

Comment: @user2779311 The function object is created when the function is defined. If the function is called multiple times, the same function object is used each time.

Answer (score 1):

This is really an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). There is really no way for the identical function to not have the identical `id` between two calls.

Presumably what you really want to know is "how can I distinguish between individual calls to this function". You can do that by taking the `id` of something which *does* change between calls, such as the `id` of the local variable `a`.

```py
def countmem(a):
    print("countmem with", id(a))
    if a==0:
        return
    print("end of countmem with", id(a))
    return countmem(a-1)
```

The two `print`s are not really necessary, but they should illustrate that the `id` *within* the same call will not change, which is presumably also important.

Notice that I also added a `return` statement at the end, though with the current design, the function will always `return None` anyway.
Forgetting to return something from a recursive function is a common beginner problem, so I'm bringing it up tangentially.

Comment: I created a local variable count in the function and  i am getting the same id for count for all calls. whereas id for variable a differs for each call. Is it because of the value. since count for all calls starts with 0 whereas a is different for each call.

Comment: Without seeing your code we can only speculate. Sounds like you set it to a smald integer value and didn't change it between calls. Perhaps (accept this answer and) post a new question about this new problem.

Comment: def countmem(a):
   count=0
   print("count=",count,id(countmem),id(a),id(count))

Comment: As you can see, posting code in comments is not a good idea, and asking new questions in comrents is also problematic. I repeat, if the previous comment didn't settle this for you, ask a new question.

Comment: Small integers are special in Python because it preallocate an `id` for them at startup. This is a FAQ and thus probably a duplicate of an (or probably several) existing questions.

Comment: Even a large value if assigned to count gives same id. I check that by assigning 10000